# Reduce Image resolution

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image that i need to reduce it's it resolution without in an approach other than resizing. I tried to change the Dpi but apparently my image doesn't have a DPI (i don't know if that is possible). I want my image with low resolution for an object detection code. Moreover, i tried using filters such as "GuassianBlur" and other image processing approaches for a better detection however, i want a solution for lowering my image resolution.

```
im = Image.open("car.png")
im.save("Dpi_test.png", dpi=(10, 10))
```

This was the code i used for dpi, when i tried to print the dpi using this function, it gave me KeyError:

```
print(im.info['dpi'])
```

For more information these are the results i wish for:

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jP94.png) for sample image.

Any help in how can i reduce the resolution of an image would be more than great! Thank you

Update!

An edited clarification concerning my question: After the help of one of the commenters he suggested to blur and decimate my image, does anyone has a way to do that? I guess it is something related to down-sampling! Not sure thou!

Update 2 !!
Question answered with 2 approaches, big thanks!

Comment: Low resolution doesnt give you accurate solution but the oppositely inaccurate solutions. Low resolution  just increase the speed.

Comment: @PythonCoder100 Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62282695/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk Yes!! How can i lower the resolution thou? any help?

Comment: @BelalHomaidan Thank u for the advice

Comment: What do you call image resolution, exactly ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Number of pixels in an image.. Look at my sample image for more explanation on my required goal.

Comment: Strongly blur the image, then decimate (i.e. take every fifth pixel or so).

Comment: @YvesDaoust Isn't there another way to lower the resolution other than blurring?

Comment: Not sure what you are really after, but try getting image width and height, resizing to 16x16 and then resizing back to original width and height.

Comment: There is no way to reduce the number of pixels besides resizing or cropping, if that is what you mean by resolution. If you mean density, then changing the density of a raster image, will make no difference until you print it. It does not affect the number of pixels. If you want to reduce the file size without changing the dimensions, then you need to compress the file. JPG would give you the most flexibility in doing that, since it is lossy compression. PNG is not loss and so cannot compress as much.

Comment: @fmw42 I guess what i meant by lowering the resolution is like what "Yves Daoust" meant! i want to downsample my image!

Comment: Does it have to be opencv, or would a PIL solution be fine as well?

Comment: @Roy2012 It doesn't matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PIL, I'm reducing the image to a thumbnail and then transforming it back to the original size:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("1jP94.png")
orig_size = im.size
print(orig_size)
display(im)

==> (142, 155)
```

[image]

```
im.thumbnail([32, 32])
display(im)
```

[image]

```
im = im.transform(orig_size, Image.EXTENT, (0,0, 32, 32))
display(im)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the ones that want to implement this on OpenCV:

Using the PIL to reduce the image to a thumbnail and then transforming it back to the original size as answered above, this is the same code as above in addition to converting PIL images to OpenCV images:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy
import cv2

im = Image.open("image.png")
orig_size = im.size
print(orig_size)
open_cv_image = numpy.array(im)
open_cv_image = open_cv_image[:, :, ::-1].copy()
cv2.imshow("original", open_cv_image)
im.thumbnail([32, 32])
open_cv_image = numpy.array(im)
open_cv_image = open_cv_image[:, :, ::-1].copy()
cv2.imshow("thumbnail", open_cv_image)
im = im.transform(orig_size, Image.EXTENT, (0,0, 32, 32))
open_cv_image = numpy.array(im)
open_cv_image = open_cv_image[:, :, ::-1].copy()
cv2.imshow("result", open_cv_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Note this is what I suggested yesterday in the comments 

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ohh Thank you :D i guess i didn't understand what u meant directly until someone did some further explanations!